# Best practices/optimization concerning using base_url() of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, optimization

My questions refers to base_url(), which is a helper function of codeigniter. The idea is that it grabs the base_url of my application and allows me to echo it anywhere on any of my view pages.

Below is an example of where I'd use base_url().

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I sometimes call it several times in a DOM load and was wondering if it would be a good idea to store it into a php variable, rather than call the base_url fuynction each time. Like so:

```
<?php 
  $this->load->helper('url'); 
  $base_url = base_url(); // Set to variable, so we don't method call each time
?>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I know this is a rather novice question, but I've been pretty OCD concerning optimization and am wondering if this addition of code would be worth its weight. I would have to add the defining of variable twice, as I use base_url() in both my head and body. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It'll store a couple bytes of data in your server's memory temporary to remove the overhead of a couple function calls, seems like a good trade imo. Not that it'd make a noticeable change unless you have a couple thousand users loading your page simultaneously.

Comment: Would it be viable to store the $baseurl into a session, so that I could call it in both my head and body tags?

Comment: Sessions? Are you using the var inside different scope functions? Yes, you can either use a global var or just store it in the `$_SESSION` which is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From performance point of view it doesn't matter either way. Do whatever makes your code easier to read/maintain. Do not place it in a session though.

As a side note, you should not use PHP in the first place if you are concerned about micro optimizations as it is one of the slowest things out there when it comes to raw processing power.

Comment: +1 for cussing php, but on topic, any solid reason to not use `$_SESSION`? It'll be kept server-side and you can access it from any scope without having to declare `global myVar;` as with global vars as far as I can see. Sure, it's not the best practice, but should work.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté because `$_SESSION` is stored on disk/memcache server/whatever-other-solution-that-is-much-slower-than-variable-or-function-call

Comment: Oh damn my stupidity. :P I knew they took more resources from the server, but didn't realize it was in the form of disk/memcache.

Comment: Haha, I'm not going to revert out of php at this point, but I'll look into that in the future. Performance-wise, this optimization is not worth it then?

Comment: @JereJamesRutter Well you shouldn't, web applications are usually I/O bound so the CPU sits idle most of the time anyway even if you had better raw performance. YMMV on that. If your app is well-rounded (that is, it does much more expensive stuff like database I/O), the time spent in doing those base_url calls is probably `0.00001%`, so yes it wouldn't be worth it :P If you really doubt it, you can always use a profiler.

Comment: @Esailija Thanks for the great info. Do you have any recommendations on a profiler I could use?

Comment: @JereJamesRutter http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html. Also I'd like to say that this "OCD" is very common among beginner programmers . What matters more than such micro optimizations is `O(n)` algorithm over `O(n²)` and doing 1 database query instead of n database queries and so on.